# google-translate returns "Invalid JSON payload received"

Tags: python, google-translate

Using Python samples from GoogleCloudPlatform\python-docs-samples-master\python-docs-samples-master\translate\cloud-client. When I try to translate using translate-text-with-model, I get the error

> python snippets.py translate-text-with-model es "How are you Grandma"
>   *google.cloud.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "model": Cannot bind 'nmt'. Field 'model' could not be found in request message. (GET https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?target=es&q=How+are+you+Grandma&model=nmt)*

Can any one point out what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this problem. I resolved the issue by passing 'model' as null. I am using PHP but in theory it should work for Python.

```
$translation = $translate->translate($text, [
        'target' => $target,
        'source' => $source,
        'model' => null
    ]);
```

Comment: But how do we know we are using the Neural Network Model to translate, then ?

Comment: Did you apply to be part of the trial? Last time I looked it wasn't open access.

Comment: Yeah.. I have the credentials etc.  Feels something silly and fundamental, but not able to figure this out.

Comment: Hey Ramesh, did Johnathans solution work for you, or what's happening now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is already solved but I faced the same problem and realized that the request.json wasn't specified properly.

Fix your request JSON by looking up the current link:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations/translateText

Also I made the mistake of not matching JSON with respect to the API version.

I used a JSON format for v2 Translate API with v3 API.